# I am getting error while installing Xgboost on pydriod 3 App (An android app for python)

Tags: python, android, installation, xgboost

Error while installing xgboost
Collecting xgboost
Using cached xgboost-1.7.1.tar.gz (843 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from xgboost) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from xgboost) (1.7.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: xgboost
Building wheel for xgboost (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1551 lines of output]
INFO:root:running bdist_wheel
INFO:root:running build
INFO:root:running build_py
INFO:root:creating build

```
      ############################
      # Package would be ignored #
      ############################
      Python recognizes 'xgboost.src.collective' as an importable package,
      but it is not listed in the `packages` configuration of setuptools.

      'xgboost.src.collective' has been automatically added to the distribution only
      because it may contain data files, but this behavior is likely to change
      in future versions of setuptools (and therefore is considered deprecated).

      Please make sure that 'xgboost.src.collective' is included as a package by using
      the `packages` configuration field or the proper discovery methods
      (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
      instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

      You can read more about "package discovery" and "data files" on setuptools
      documentation page.


  !!

    check.warn(importable)
  /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py:202: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'xgboost.src.common' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.
      !!

  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/logging.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/json.h:8,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/collective/communicator.h:5,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/collective/communicator.cc:4:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:74: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api.cc.o] Error 1
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:102: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/communicator.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/communicator.cc.o] Error 1
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/collective/socket.h:55,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/collective/socket.cc:4:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:116: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/socket.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/socket.cc.o] Error 1
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/data.h:13,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/c_api/./c_api_utils.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/c_api/./c_api_error.h:12,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/c_api/c_api_error.cc:8:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/logging.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/../data/adapter.h:19,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/column_matrix.h:19,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/column_matrix.cc:5:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api_error.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api_error.cc.o] Error 1
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:144: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/column_matrix.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/column_matrix.cc.o] Error 1
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:262: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/all' failed
  make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/all] Error 2
  Makefile:154: recipe for target 'all' failed
  make: *** [all] Error 2
  WARNING:XGBoost build_ext:Disabling OpenMP support.
  INFO:XGBoost build_ext:Run CMake command: ['cmake', 'xgboost', '-GUnix Makefiles', '-DUSE_OPENMP=0', '-DUSE_CUDA=0', '-DUSE_NCCL=0', '-DBUILD_WITH_SHARED_NCCL=0', '-DHIDE_CXX_SYMBOLS=1', '-DUSE_HDFS=0', '-DUSE_AZURE=0', '-DUSE_S3=0', '-DPLUGIN_DENSE_PARSER=0']
  -- CMake version 3.20.3
  -- xgboost VERSION: 1.7.1
  -- Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR)
  -- /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/dmlc-core/cmake/build_config.h.in -> include/dmlc/build_config.h
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39
  Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target dmlc
  [  1%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/io/line_split.cc.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/config.cc.o
  [  3%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/io/recordio_split.cc.o
  [  4%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/io/indexed_recordio_split.cc.o
  [  6%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/io/input_split_base.cc.o
  [  8%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/data.cc.o
  [  9%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/recordio.cc.o
  [  9%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/io.cc.o
  [ 10%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/io/filesys.cc.o
  [ 12%] Building CXX object dmlc-core/CMakeFiles/dmlc.dir/src/io/local_filesys.cc.o
  [ 13%] Linking CXX static library libdmlc.a
  [ 13%] Built target dmlc
  [ 14%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api_error.cc.o
  [ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api.cc.o
  [ 17%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/socket.cc.o
  [ 18%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/hist_util.cc.o
  [ 20%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/column_matrix.cc.o
  [ 20%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/charconv.cc.o
  [ 21%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/common.cc.o
  [ 23%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/communicator.cc.o
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/hist_util.cc:9:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/logging.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/charconv.cc:35:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/logging.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/json.h:8,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/collective/communicator.h:5,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/collective/communicator.cc:4:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/logging.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/common.cc:7:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/c_api/c_api.cc:10:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:130: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/charconv.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/charconv.cc.o] Error 1
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:172: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/hist_util.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/hist_util.cc.o] Error 1
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:102: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/communicator.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/communicator.cc.o] Error 1
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:158: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/common.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/common.cc.o] Error 1
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:74: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api.cc.o] Error 1
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/collective/socket.h:55,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/collective/socket.cc:4:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:116: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/socket.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/collective/socket.cc.o] Error 1
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/logging.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/../data/adapter.h:19,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/column_matrix.h:19,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/common/column_matrix.cc:5:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/data.h:13,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/c_api/./c_api_utils.h:14,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/c_api/./c_api_error.h:12,
                   from /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/src/c_api/c_api_error.cc:8:
  /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/xgboost/include/xgboost/base.h:59:10: fatal error: parallel/algorithm: No such file or directory
     59 | #include <parallel/algorithm>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:144: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/column_matrix.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/common/column_matrix.cc.o] Error 1
  src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api_error.cc.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/c_api/c_api_error.cc.o] Error 1
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:262: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/all' failed
  make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/objxgboost.dir/all] Error 2
  Makefile:154: recipe for target 'all' failed
  make: *** [all] Error 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/setup.py", line 198, in build_cmake_extension
      self.build(src_dir, build_dir, gen, build_tool, use_omp=1)
    File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/setup.py", line 138, in build
      subprocess.check_call([build_tool, '-j' + str(nproc)],
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-j8']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>        File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/setup.py", line 334, in <module>
      setup(name='xgboost',
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 325, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 346, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 468, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 494, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/setup.py", line 206, in build_extension
      self.build_cmake_extension()
    File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/setup.py", line 201, in build_cmake_extension
      self.build(src_dir, build_dir, gen, build_tool, use_omp=0)
    File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-xo0kylfh/xgboost_e53112f2dbf34e678c6cec71c834ce4d/setup.py", line 138, in build
      subprocess.check_call([build_tool, '-j' + str(nproc)],
    File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-j8']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for xgboost
Running setup.py clean for xgboost
Failed to build xgboost
Installing collected packages: xgboost
Running setup.py install for xgboost ... error
error: subprocess-exited-w
'''